# Написать фильтр для checkbox во Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, сортировка

Нужно выводить данные по определенным требованиям - по полу.

```
<v-radio label="Both" name="gender" value=""></v-radio>
<v-radio label="Male" name="gender" value="Male" ></v-radio>
<v-radio label="Female"  name="gender" value="Female"></v-radio>
```

Данные о людях хранятся в `store(vuex)` -

```
guides:   [
      { id: 1,popularGuide: true, name: 'Karina',  rate: '41',gender: 'female', photo: require('./assets/img/person1.jpg')},  
      { id: 2,popularGuide: true,name: 'Nicolas', rate: '32', gender: 'male',photo: require('./assets/img/person2.jpg') },
```

При нажатии на определенный `checkbox` вывести весь список, или только женщин, или только мужчин.

Сюда выводятся данные:

`<v-flex xs4 sm4 md4 lg4 v-for="guide in guides" :key="guide.name">`  и так далее.

Я пробовала и `filters` и через `getters` и через библиотеку **fuse.js**.

Пример из одной моей попытки:

```
   if ( '' !== gender ) {
      // 
      guides= guides.filter( function ( guide) {
        return guide.gender === gender;
      } );
    }
```

Подскажите, через что лучше сделать выборку и как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот один из вариантов для решения вашей задачи:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="ru">

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-container>

          <v-radio-group v-model="filterGender" @change="sortGuide">
            <v-radio label="both" key="both" value="both"></v-radio>
            <v-radio label="male" key="male" value="male"></v-radio>
            <v-radio label="female" key="female" value="female"></v-radio>
          </v-radio-group>

          <v-layout row wrap v-if="sortAll.length>0">
            <v-flex xs12 sm3 md2 v-for="guide in sortAll" :key="guide.id">
              <v-card class="mx-2 mb-3">
                <v-img height="200px" :src="guide.photo"></v-img>

                <v-card-title primary-title>
                  <div>
                    <h3 class="headline mb-0">{{guide.name}}</h3>
                    <div> {{ guide.gender }} </div>
                  </div>
                </v-card-title>

                <v-card-actions>
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                  <v-btn icon>
                    <v-icon>mdi-thumb-up</v-icon> {{ guide.rate }}
                  </v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
              </v-card>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>

        </v-container>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.0/vue.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>
    var store = new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        guides: [{
            id: 1,
            popularGuide: true,
            name: 'Steve',
            rate: '41',
            gender: 'male',
            photo: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Steve_Jobs_WWDC07.jpg/609px-Steve_Jobs_WWDC07.jpg'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            popularGuide: true,
            name: 'Steve',
            rate: '32',
            gender: 'male',
            photo: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Steve_Jobs_WWDC07.jpg/609px-Steve_Jobs_WWDC07.jpg'
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            popularGuide: true,
            name: 'Steve',
            rate: '56',
            gender: 'male',
            photo: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Steve_Jobs_WWDC07.jpg/609px-Steve_Jobs_WWDC07.jpg'
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            popularGuide: true,
            name: 'Marilyn',
            rate: '112',
            gender: 'female',
            photo: 'https://previews.123rf.com/images/apoev/apoev1812/apoev181200157/126744487-person-gray-photo-placeholder-woman-in-costume-on-white-background.jpg'
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            popularGuide: true,
            name: 'Marilyn',
            rate: '222',
            gender: 'female',
            photo: 'https://previews.123rf.com/images/apoev/apoev1812/apoev181200157/126744487-person-gray-photo-placeholder-woman-in-costume-on-white-background.jpg'
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            popularGuide: true,
            name: 'Marilyn',
            rate: '333',
            gender: 'female',
            photo: 'https://previews.123rf.com/images/apoev/apoev1812/apoev181200157/126744487-person-gray-photo-placeholder-woman-in-costume-on-white-background.jpg'
          },
          {
            id: 7,
            popularGuide: true,
            name: 'Steve',
            rate: '46',
            gender: 'male',
            photo: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Steve_Jobs_WWDC07.jpg/609px-Steve_Jobs_WWDC07.jpg'
          },
          {
            id: 8,
            popularGuide: true,
            name: 'Steve',
            rate: '334',
            gender: 'male',
            photo: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/Steve_Jobs_WWDC07.jpg/609px-Steve_Jobs_WWDC07.jpg'
          }
        ]
      }
    })



    var app = new Vue({
      store,
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      el: '#app',
      computed: {
        ...Vuex.mapState(['guides'])
      },
      data: function() {
        return {
          filterGender: 'both',
          sortAll: []
        }
      },
      methods: {
        sortGuide() {
          var self = this;
          var all = [];
          if (this.filterGender != 'both') {
            all = this.guides.filter(x => x.gender == self.filterGender);
          } else {
            all = this.guides;
          }
          this.sortAll = all;
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        this.sortGuide();
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: время пройдёт и никому не будет интересно, быстро вы написали (на скорую руку) или не очень. Главное качество ответа. Добавьте мужские портреты и выборки будут смотреться более реально

Comment: Согласитесь, ведь выглядит теперь намного более выигрышно. Выборки по полу, теперь действительно выборки. А плюс я вам поставил, ещё до первого моего комментария.

Answer (score 3):

Геттеры применяются когда нужно вернуть измененную информацию из хранилища, например отфильтровать список. В вашем случае необходимо передавать [аргумент геттеру](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/getters.html#%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8n%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC), т.к. нужен массив по указанному критерию: `gender`.

```
// ex.: store.js

getters: {
  getByGender: state => gender => {
    // Если не выбран пол, возвращаем весь список.
    // Либо производим фильтрацию по указанному критерию.
    return gender ?
      state.guides.filter(guide => guide.gender === gender) :
      state.guides;
  }
}
```

Для доступа к геттеру из компонента используется локальное вычисляемой свойство:

```
// ex.: component.vue

data() {
  return {
    // Пол. Изначально не выбран
    // и определен как пустая строка.
    gender: ''
  }
},

computed: {
  // Смешиваем результат mapGetters с внешним объектом computed.
  // Теперь будет доступна функция `this.getByGender`.
  ...mapGetters([
    'getByGender'
  ]),

  // Локальное вычисляемое свойство.
  filteredGuides() {
    return this.getByGender(this.gender);
  }
}
```

```
<!-- При использовании обычных радиокнопок -->
<input type="radio" v-model="gender" value="">
<input type="radio" v-model="gender" value="male">
<input type="radio" v-model="gender" value="female">

<!-- При использовании vuetify радиокнопок -->
<v-radio-group v-model="gender">
  <v-radio label="All" value=""></v-radio>
  <v-radio label="Male" value="male"></v-radio>
  <v-radio label="Female" value="female"></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>

<!-- Берем список гидов из вычисляемого поля `filteredGuides` -->
<v-flex xs4 sm4 md4 lg4 v-for="(guide, index) in filteredGuides" :key="guide.name">
  {{ guide.name }} [{{ guide.gender }}]
</v-flex>
```

**Демо**:

```js
const guides = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Karina',
  gender: 'female',
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Nicolas',
  gender: 'male',
}];

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    guides: guides
  },

  // Геттеры применяются когда нужно
  // вернуть измененную информацию из хранилища.
  // https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/getters.html#стиnь-обращения-как-к-методам
  getters: {
    getByGender: state => gender => {
      // Если не выбран пол, возвращаем весь список.
      // Либо производим фильтрацию по указанному критерию.
      return gender ?
        state.guides.filter(guide => guide.gender === gender) :
        state.guides;
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data: {
    // Пол. Изначально не выбран
    // и определен как пустая строка.
    gender: ''
  },

  computed: {
    // Смешиваем результат mapGetters с внешним объектом computed.
    // Теперь будет доступна функция `this.getByGender`.
    // При модульном подходе без `Vuex.` только - `...mapGetters`.
    ...Vuex.mapGetters([
      'getByGender'
    ]),

    // Локальное вычисляемое свойство.
    filteredGuides() {
      return this.getByGender(this.gender);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css'>


<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>

      <!-- При использовании обычных радиокнопок -->
      <input type="radio" v-model="gender" value="">
      <input type="radio" v-model="gender" value="male">
      <input type="radio" v-model="gender" value="female">

      <!-- При использовании vuetify радиокнопок -->
      <v-radio-group v-model="gender">
        <v-radio label="All" value=""></v-radio>
        <v-radio label="Male" value="male"></v-radio>
        <v-radio label="Female" value="female"></v-radio>
      </v-radio-group>

      <!-- Берем список гидов из вычисляемого поля `filteredGuides` -->
      <v-flex xs4 sm4 md4 lg4 v-for="(guide, index) in filteredGuides" :key="guide.name">
        {{ guide.name }} [{{ guide.gender }}]
      </v-flex>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuex@2.0.0'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14'></script>
```

**PS** В заголовке и тексте вопроса фигурирует `checkbox`, но в одном из фрагментов кода `v-radio`.